# Can we run multiple functions each with timeit in the same module

Tags: python, timeit

I would like to write multiple functions in the same Python module, each of which is a separate profiling test using `timeit`, so that I can use command line argument to specify which one to run. A naive example (profiling.py) would be:

```
import sys
import timeit

def foo():

    setup = """
    import random
    """

    foo_1 = """
    for i in range(1000):
        random.randint(0, 99) + random.randint(0, 99)
    """

    foo_2 = """
    for i in range(1000):
        random.randint(0, 99) + random.randint(0, 99)
    """

    foo_3 = """
    for i in range(1000):
        random.randint(0, 99) + random.randint(0, 99)
    """

    print 'foo_1', timeit.Timer(foo_1, setup).timeit(1000)
    print 'foo_2', timeit.Timer(foo_2, setup).timeit(1000)
    print 'foo_3', timeit.Timer(foo_3, setup).timeit(1000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
        if (sys.argv[1] == 'foo'):
            foo()
    else:
        print 'Which profiling do you want to run?'
        print 'available:'
        print '    foo'
```

However, when I try `python profiling.py foo`, I get error like the following:

```
foo_1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "profiling.py", line 32, in <module>
    foo()
  File "profiling.py", line 25, in foo
    print 'foo_1', timeit.Timer(foo_1, setup).timeit(1000)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 136, in __init__
    code = compile(src, dummy_src_name, "exec")
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6
    _t0 = _timer()
                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I have searched for the usual space/tab indention error in the code, but didn't find any. Hence I wonder if it is because I wrap a `timeit` test inside a function, and this is not allowed?

Comment: What happens if you remove the whitespace from the strings you are passing to timeit?  (e.g. `foo_1="for i in range(1000):\n    random.randint(0, 99) + random.randint(0, 99)"`)

Comment: Did you by any chance copy and paste that line? A lot of the times when you copy and paste you will encounter that error due to mismatched tab sizes or tabs as white-spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
import sys
import timeit

def foo():

    setup = """
import random
"""

    foo_1 = """
for i in range(1000):
    random.randint(0, 99) + random.randint(0, 99)
"""

    foo_2 = """
for i in range(1000):
    random.randint(0, 99) + random.randint(0, 99)
"""

    foo_3 = """
for i in range(1000):
    random.randint(0, 99) + random.randint(0, 99)
"""

    print 'foo_1', timeit.Timer(foo_1, setup).timeit(1000)
    print 'foo_2', timeit.Timer(foo_2, setup).timeit(1000)
    print 'foo_3', timeit.Timer(foo_3, setup).timeit(1000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
        if (sys.argv[1] == 'foo'):
            foo()
    else:
        print 'Which profiling do you want to run?'
        print 'available:'
        print '    foo'
```

The problem is that your strings that you're passing as `setup` and `foo_1`, etc. *are indented* since you've lined them up with your indented code inside the function.  However, when that string gets executed by `timeit`, it raises the indentation error you see because the code should not be indented.  This is essentially the same thing that would happen if you tried...

```
exec("    import sys")
```

as the first thing in your interactive interpreter session.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. So I can fix the error by doing `setup = """import random"""`(all in one line), **without** making any change to foo_1. I wonder why?

Comment: `timeit` must do some "cleanup" on the argument to be run, but not on the setup-code.

Comment: @MLister What's funny about that?  You don't have any indentation in front of your setup code -- only a newline (blank lines are perfectly acceptable in python).

Comment: ooops, sorry I misunderstood your point. thanks for pointing  out.

Answer (score 0):

mgilson gave a great answer.  But personally, I find the visually-dedented lines in the heredoc strings distracting.  It also breaks [the vim python code folding I use](https://github.com/klen/python-mode).

You can get the same effect by writing the lines separately, and joining them, like so:

```
import sys
import timeit


def foo():

    setup = 'import random'

    foo_1 = '\n'.join([
        'for i in range(1000):',
        '    random.randint(0, 99) + random.randint(0, 99)',
    ])

    foo_2 = '\n'.join([
        'for i in range(1000):',
        '    random.randint(0, 99) + random.randint(0, 99)',
    ])

    foo_3 = '\n'.join([
        'for i in range(1000):',
        '    random.randint(0, 99) + random.randint(0, 99)',
    ])

    print 'foo_1', timeit.Timer(foo_1, setup).timeit(1000)
    print 'foo_2', timeit.Timer(foo_2, setup).timeit(1000)
    print 'foo_3', timeit.Timer(foo_3, setup).timeit(1000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
        if (sys.argv[1] == 'foo'):
            foo()
    else:
        print 'Which profiling do you want to run?'
        print 'available:'
        print '    foo'
```

You get less space on each line, but I the tradeoff is worth it for me.